# My program unexpectedly outputs None when all the conditionals has been defined. Pls advise

Tags: python, loops, conditional-statements

For some inputs such as waist_measurement = 50 and hip_measurement = 100, the program output as None. Would appreciate some help on this!

```
def waist_hip():

    #This function will calculate the waist-to-hip ratio of the user and determine if he or she has a high or low health risk

    gender = input ("What is your gender (M or F)? ")
    waist_measurement = input ("What is your waist measurement (inches)? ")
    hip_measurment = input ("What is your hip measuremnt (inches)? ")

    waist_measurement = (waist_measurement)
    hip_measurment = (hip_measurment)

    WHR_Ratio = float(waist_measurement) / float(hip_measurment)

    while gender == "M":

        if WHR_Ratio < 0.9:
            return ("Your health risk: Low")

        elif 0.9 < WHR_Ratio < 1.0:
            return ("Your health risk: Moderate")

        else:
            return ("Your health risk: High")


    while gender == "F":

        if WHR_Ratio < 0.8:
            return ("Your health risk: Low")

        elif 0.8 < WHR_Ratio < 0.89:
            return ("Your health risk: Moderate")

        else:
            WHR_Ratio = ("Your health risk: High")
            return WHR_Ratio

print (waist_hip())
```

It should output based on the conditions given since all inputs should fall within the defined boundaries

Comment: I'm not seeing the behavior you're describing using any variety of inputs. How are you running the code?

Comment: working fine on my side.. in your example  `waist_measurement = 50 and hip_measurement = 100,` `Your health risk: Low` showing..

Comment: Oh, are you inputting something other than `M` or `F`? Do you need to check against the lowercased version and/or validate that it's strictly one of those two?

Answer (score 1):

Covering all the aspects of the user..!

**Changes**

```
(1) checking if gender is correct or not.
(2) gender input taken as upper case.
```

**Code:-**

```
def waist_hip():
    gender = input ("What is your gender (M or F)? ").upper()
    
    if gender not in ["M","F"]:
        return "You have not enter the correct gender"
    
    waist_measurement = input ("What is your waist measurement (inches)? ")
    hip_measurment = input ("What is your hip measuremnt (inches)? ")
    waist_measurement = (waist_measurement)
    hip_measurment = (hip_measurment)
    WHR_Ratio = float(waist_measurement) / float(hip_measurment)
    while gender == "M":

        if WHR_Ratio < 0.9:
            return ("Your health risk: Low")

        elif 0.9 < WHR_Ratio < 1.0:
            return ("Your health risk: Moderate")

        else:
            return ("Your health risk: High")
    while gender == "F":

        if WHR_Ratio < 0.8:
            return ("Your health risk: Low")

        elif 0.8 < WHR_Ratio < 0.89:
            return ("Your health risk: Moderate")

        else:
            WHR_Ratio = ("Your health risk: High")
            return WHR_Ratio
    
print(waist_hip())
```

Answer (score -1):

The code works fines for me. Here is the output

```
**What is your gender (M or F)? M**
What is your waist measurement (inches)? 30
What is your hip measuremnt (inches)? 34
Your health risk: Low
```

And below is the output u might be getting:

```
 **What is your gender (M or F)? m**
    What is your waist measurement (inches)? 20
    What is your hip measuremnt (inches)? 36
    None
```

Conclusion: Your input in case sensitive here! if you take M/F as your input then the result is coming if your a taking m/f your are getting **none**